# Django admin: created users have plain text password and can't login

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have a custom tab for staff users so in `admin.py` I do:

```
class StaffUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


@admin.register(StaffUser)
class AdminUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

But on the admin site, whenever I add a new user with this interface I can't log in with it since for some reason it sets it's password as plain text instead of hashing it.

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514912/django-admin-not-hashing-custom-user-password) BUT if I do that and change `StaffUser` to inherint from `AdminUser`I get this other error

```
AttributeError: type object 'StaffUser' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your models in `models.py` (or a `models` [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712889/how-to-create-a-package-of-models-in-django)), not `admin.py`.

`UserAdmin` (there is no such thing as an `AdminUser` in the Django packages) is a subclass of `ModelAdmin`, that is, a class for registering models in the Django admin. It is *not* a model subclass that you can extend to make new models.

Also, if you are trying to extend the `User` just to distinguish users with access to the Django admin site, note that there is already an [`is_staff` property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) in the default `User` model. And in any case, if you still want to extend the `User` model, you should be extending `AbstractUser` instead as [stated in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user).